# git: checking out from remote branch changes local files?

Tags: git, branch, git-remote

I just checked out to a remote branch to see the differences with the local one directly in the files. Didn't make any change at all, but when I try to come back (ck = checkout) to the master, I get the error: "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
[image: checkout from remote branch]

Edit: the error doesn't say anything about pending commits or anything [image: it just says abort]

I don't get why a checkout would make any change to files, but the fact that the checkout is from a remote branch and the error says "local files" befuddles me... The local files then have to refer to the local master branch I'm switching to, but I have just committed all changes in that master branch... (!?). 
[image: add .]
[image: local master commit]

Edit: this is the status right after the commit: 
[image]

What is that I (definitively) don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer

Discard any changes to your work tree and that may have been added to the index with

```
git checkout HEAD -- .
```

For a repository on a Windows FAT32 filesystem, tell git to ignore the execute bits on file modes.

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

after which you should be able to checkout your master branch.

```
git checkout master
```

or using your alias

```
git ck master
```

---

### Detailed Explanation

After you tell git to add all new files and changes in the current directory (`.`) and in any child directories

```
git add .
```

and then commit, notice that git tells you the file permissions changed, *e.g.*,

```
mode change 100644 => 100755 .gitignore
```

Combined with the line immediately above it

```
264 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

we conclude that the contents did not change — only the permissions.

*Context is critical for this paragraph.* Immediately after you ran `git commit -m 'many changes were not ...'`, you could have confirmed this by running `git diff origin/master`, and the output will consist of many sequences of the form

```
$ git diff origin/master
diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
[...]
```

but with no new lines inserted or lines deleted.

The appearance of your screenshots and a directory named `Desktop` lead me to believe (which your later comment confirmed) that you are using Microsoft Windows on a filesystem that does not represent the execute-mode bits, so git must be told to ignore it with `git config core.fileMode false`, which the [`git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) explains.

> **core.fileMode**
> Tells Git if the executable bit of files in the working tree is to be honored.
>
> Some filesystems lose the executable bit when a file that is marked as executable is checked out, or checks out a non-executable file with executable bit on. [`git-clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) or [`git-init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) probe the filesystem to see if it handles the executable bit correctly and this variable is automatically set as necessary.
>
> A repository, however, may be on a filesystem that handles the filemode correctly, and this variable is set to true when created, but later may be made accessible from another environment that loses the filemode (e.g. exporting ext4 via CIFS mount, visiting a Cygwin created repository with Git for Windows or Eclipse). In such a case it may be necessary to set this variable to false. See [`git-update-index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index).

### Git Philosophy

Git is exceedingly careful not to destroy your work. Before it proceeds with the checkout of master, git compares the state of your present work tree with the head of your desired branch and, for example, sees that `.gitignore` as it sits differs from `.gitignore` in master.

Because git sees uncommitted changes that it would have to overwrite to checkout master, it aborts the checkout and lets you know that you either need to throw away those changes intentionally

```
git checkout HEAD -- .
```

or put them somewhere for safe keeping with `git stash` or `git add` followed by `git commit`. With a clean work tree, you can then safely check out different branches.

### Comparing Files

For details about what exactly has changed, run one of the commands below. The correct invocation depends on context.

**After Creating Your New Commit**

You added the changes and created a commit on branch master with SHA-1 object name 644ccb8 (as seen in your screenshot of the output from `git commit -m [...]`). At the time you created it, 644ccb8 became the `HEAD` of your master branch, and to see all changes between it and `master` out on origin, run

```
git diff origin/master
```

In English, this means “Show me all the changes between `origin/master` and the tip of the branch I am currently working on.” In fact, the command above is equivalent to `git diff HEAD origin/master`, which explicitly calls for a comparison against `HEAD`.

To show the changes for one or more files named after a `--` separator, use

```
git diff origin/master -- .gitignore README.md
```

**After Staging But Before Committing**

Your screenshots do not show everything, but the text in green from the output of `git status` means that certain changes have been “staged” or added to the index. In git, we incrementally build up the next commit in the index (also referred to as the staging area or cache) with one or more invocations of `git add` and, less commonly, remove changes from the index with `git reset`. Once the index is in good shape, `git commit` adds a new commit with the contents of the index to the history.

Your screenshots show that you ran `git add .` from your repository’s root.

- Aside: Be aware that `git add .` paints with a broad brush. Sometimes that is what you want, but often it picks up more files than you intend — particularly when your `.gitignore` is missing a few patterns. After a big `git add`, always be sure to run `git status` to be sure you didn’t pick up any hitchhikers.

After running `git add` one or more times but *before* running `git commit`, to see the changes currently in the index or cache, add the `--cached` option.

```
git diff --cached
```

or to limit to one or more specific files

```
git diff --cached -- README.md
```

**Before Staging**

To see the delta between what is in your work tree and what is in the index (or cache), run one of

```
git diff
git diff -- README.md
```

This is the default mode of `git diff`.

### Detached HEAD

Note from your screen capture that your repository has a [detached HEAD](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head), defined in the documentation as

> It means simply that HEAD refers to a specific commit, as opposed to referring to a named branch.

As a rule of thumb, you generally do *not* want to checkout remote tracking branches (*e.g.*, `origin/master`), tags, or SHA-1 hashes directly if you plan to make modifications.

Comment: Hi @Greg, where in the commit output says that 'the permissions of your files changed'? I've included a screenshot of the status to show that all local master content was committed without any problem, and I can't see what you mention... And yes, there are probably many differences between local and remote folders/files, including .gitignore, but I just entered (checked-out) the remote to see it, I didn't modify anything; why would seeing a branch and then comming back to the same previous one would change anything and why would that overwrite those changes??

Comment: As the screenshots show, I just checked-out the origin/master; then why is Git showing a HEAD instead of the origin/master branch??    ...

Comment: ooh! I see; `mode change ..=>..` is a permission change. Regarding the filesystem, this repo used to be in an Ubuntu partition that broke and from which I pushed to the remote repos time ago before pasting and modifying it here in Windows; maybe this is the reason... (?). -The diff instructions didn't work: `diff --git a/.gitignore b/.gitignore` I guess it is 'git diff .gitignore origin/.gitignore` but all vers I tried  return "fatal: bad revision... " or "no such path in the working tree". `git diff master -- .gitignore` and `git diff master` result in nothing, not even an error message...

Comment: @Martin Yes, Unix filesystem permissions are exposed in a word named mode (or `st_mode` — see the [`stat` documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)). The lines with `diff --git` are part of the *output* from `git diff`, and you were not seeing output because you had already committed your changes. `git diff` is sensitive to the context in which it is run: before staging, after staging, or after committing. I attempted to clarify the answer.

Comment: I just tested what you proposed, `git checkout HEAD -- .` , hoping (finger crossed) the changes to the index you refer to are made by the `checkout remote`. It has worked out even though my system is NTFS (not FAT32). Thanks!

Comment: Yet, I'm still not sure I understand this key paragraph: "Before ... the checkout of master, git compares the state of your present work tree with the head of your desired branch..." I think 'desired branch' refers to the remote where the HEAD is pointing. I used to believe that the 'present work tree' was where the head points to, but it seems it is not the case if HEAD doesn't point to a branch, as here. Am I right?

Comment: For others who doesn't understand this, this helped me: 
Moving (checkingout) to a remote does not change your current branch, i.e. remotes are not branches, just commits, even though in GitHub you select the branches to display certain commit. This was hard for me to interiorize, but AFAIK, and assuming my previous comment is right, this is how it works. It helps understanding that you never work on a remote, your work tree will always commit to a local branch -later you can push it.

Comment: In `git diff HEAD origin/master`, even if you have checkout origin/master and it is your current HEAD, the 'HEAD' refers to the local head. So, it doesn't refer to your current checked-out head if it is a remote, but to the local one you will be working with. In this sense, the local one is your current working head, rather than what you would think it is your current head if you checked-out the remote. Remotes, therefore, are never your current head (nor your current branch as we said they are just treated as commits).

Comment: And to understand the part of the permissions:The numbers in
`mode change 100644 => 100755`
are codes for permission type. If file code ends in  644: means you can read and write the file or directory and other users can only read it. Suitable for public text files. ||
755: means you can do anything with the file or directory, and other users can read and execute it but not alter it. Suitable for programs and directories you want to make publicly available.